# Ansible alias in separate file

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to separate my vars from the playbook file.
My vars use an alias to make things easier.

Example of my `playbook.yaml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  name: playbook name
  vars:
    login: &login
     username: "{{ login.user }}"
     password: "{{ login.pass }}"
  vars_files:
    - creds.yaml

  tasks:
  - name: using creds
    some_module:
      some_command: true
      <<: *login
```

How can I move the **"vars"** section to a file outside the playbook and keep the same template inside **"tasks"**?

Comment: YAML aliases (which aren't specific to Ansible) can only refer to content in the same YAML document.

Comment: @larsks Thanks, Is it possible to share variables between files in the same way without using anchor / alias?

Answer (score 0):

Your way to achieve that is to create a proper inventory and use the inventory variables. [ansible inventory docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

Create this schema tree:

- hosts (directory)

  - group_vars (directory)
  - host_vars (directory)
  - hosts-groups (directory)
  - hosts-all (file)

Then either you choose to define your hosts individually in the **hosts-all**

```
localhost ansible_ssh_host=x.x.x.x {{ potentially any other needed argument/variable }}
```

Or You group hosts in groups and define new group in **hosts/hosts-groups**: Create a file with the desired group name, ex: **hosts/hosts-groups/local** and inside it define your host-group

```
[local]
localhost
```

And then, either in the hosts_var or group_vars (depending on your first step), you create a file either with host name or group name, and inside it, you write your variables. Ex (by group): Create **hosts/group_vars/local** and inside it write your variables

```
login: user1
pass: pass1
```

And then automatically, your play will search the right vars for each hosts according to your inventory structure.